# How to checkout gitflow branches?

Tags: git, github, git-flow

Okay, so I have some repository and I create a feature branch using git flow...

```
 git flow feature start refactor
```

Now I hack around at it for a bit and decide to test code on another system...

```
 git add code
 git commit -m 'refactored stuff'
 git flow feature publish refactor
```

Now I have some branch in github named feature/refactor. Now I go to another machine and browse to the project folder.

How do I check that new branch out? I've tried...

```
 git checkout feature/refactor
```

... and git doesn't like it because there's a slash in the argument? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I've also tried...

```
 git flow feature pull refactor
```

... but git doesn't seem to like that either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get a branch from remote, you have to specify the repo with the `-t` option.

```
git checkout -t origin/feature/refactor
```

You can change origin for whatever the name of your remote is. This command create a new branch in your local repository named `feature/refactor` and that branch is going to be connected with your remote branch `origin/feature/refactor` that you published before.

There is a command to track also in gitflow, you should try it:

```
git flow feature track refactor
```